# Magento 2 pdf - product image displaying upside down

Tags: php, magento, pdf, magento2

I have added code into the php file to generate pdfs in magento. Currently the image for each product is displaying in the column however it is displaying upside down.

My code:

```
foreach ($line as $column) 
{
   if($i == 1 && $flag)
   {
     $i++;
     if(array_key_exists('is_image', $column) && !is_null($column['text']))
     {
       $image = \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($column['text']);
       $feed = $column['feed'];
       $page->drawImage($image, $feed, $this->y, $feed+70, $this->y-80);
       $maxHeight = 100;
     }
     continue 1;
   }
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the Emizen Tech module for printing pdf invoices with product images. I fixed it changing this line

```
$page->drawImage($image, $feed, $this->y, $feed+70, $this->y-80);
```

to:

```
$page->drawImage($image, $feed, $this->y-80, $feed+70, $this->y);
```

Now the image will be correctly displayed on the invoice.